# Spring Boot Test: Test Response throws "Could not find acceptable representation" , App works correctly

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, testing, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot to create an app. When I run my application, and test the service, I get this which is correct.

[image: Picture of service running]

However, when I run my test which looks like this:

```
public class CatalogControllerTet {
    private MockMvc mvc;
    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;
    @Autowired
    private CatalogRepository catalogRepository;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        this.mvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.context).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void getHello() throws Exception {

        MvcResult r = mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders
                .get("/catalogs")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).andReturn();
        String content = r.getResponse().getContentAsString();
        int i = 100;
    }
}
```

When I put a breakpoint in my test, I see this.  One thing I noticed is that I don't see anything in the "supportedMediaTypes" list mentioning JSON.

I've seen some other similar questions as mine, but they were traced back to the response object not having any getters/setters or something having to do with Jackson libraries.  The fact that the service starts up and runs correctly means that it isn't those issues.

[image]

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you share details about endpoint implementation? Also, don't you need to make your test class aware of a config class / file?

Comment: There really isn't an endpoint configuration, it's just there..

"Ampersand"RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
"Ampersand"SpringBootTest
"Ampersand"EnableConfigurationProperties
"Ampersand"ComponentScan("com.curator.application.domain,com.curator.application.repositories,com.curator.application.services")
"Ampersand"EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.curator.application.repositories"})
"Ampersand"DataJpaTest

Is at the top of my Test file.  Right now, I'm just trying to get a POC running corretly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had @DataJpaTest listed as an annotation on the Integration test file.  Why that manifests as this error, I'll never know, but it did.

Works:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class CatalogControllerITTest {
...
```

Does not work:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@DataJpaTest
public class CatalogControllerITTest {
...
```

Very, very astonishing and insidious behavior because the annotation would have never been suspected as of having any effect on how the servlet would handle the response.

Answer (score -1):

Your controller can look something like the following.

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/catalogs", produces={"application/json"})
    @ResponseBody
    public String catalogs() {
        return "{\"catalogslist\":[], \"tupleslist\":[]}";
    }

}
```

Then the following test succeeds.

```
package hello;

import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.content;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockServletContext;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MvcResult;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = MockServletContext.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class HelloControllerTest {

    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        mvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new HelloController()).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void getHello() throws Exception {

        MvcResult r = mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders
                .get("/")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).andReturn();


        mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/catalogs").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().string(equalTo("{\"catalogslist\":[], \"tupleslist\":[]}")));
    }
}
```

The test succeeds.

[image]

If you need a boilerplate you are welcome to use my [boilerplate](https://github.com/montao/spring-boot-loaded) for a new spring boot project. You just clone it and run it:

```
git clone https://github.com/montao/spring-boot-loaded.git
Cloning into 'spring-boot-loaded'...
remote: Counting objects: 25, done.
remote: Total 25 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 25
Unpacking objects: 100% (25/25), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
dac@dac-Latitude-E7450 ~/spring-boot-loaded> ls
spring-boot-loaded/
dac@dac-Latitude-E7450 ~/spring-boot-loaded> cd spring-boot-loaded/
dac@dac-Latitude-E7450 ~/s/spring-boot-loaded> gradle bootRun
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
:compileJava
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes
:findMainClass
:bootRun

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.3.6.RELEASE)
```

A more advanced example is actually creating json from a java object and then testing it.

Controller

```
package hello;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerationException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.w3c.dom.Entity;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.GET;

@RestController
class HelloController {
    private class User {

        private String name;

        public int getAge() {
            return age;
        }

        void setAge(int age) {
            this.age = age;
        }

        private int age;

        public List<String> getMessages() {
            return messages;
        }

        void setMessages(List<String> messages) {
            this.messages = messages;
        }

        private List<String> messages;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        //getters and setters
    }

    private User createDummyUser() {

        User user = new User();

        user.setName("Mallory");
        user.setAge(33);

        List<String> msg = new ArrayList<>();
        msg.add("hello jackson 1");
        msg.add("hello jackson 2");
        msg.add("hello jackson 3");

        user.setMessages(msg);

        return user;

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/catalogs2", produces = {"application/json"})
    @ResponseBody
    public String catalogs() {
        String jsonInString = "";
        String json = "";
        User user = createDummyUser();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            //Convert object to JSON string and save into file directly
            mapper.writeValue(new File("user.json"), user);

            //Convert object to JSON string
            jsonInString = mapper.writeValueAsString(user);
            System.out.println(jsonInString);

            //Convert object to JSON string and pretty print
            jsonInString = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(user);
            ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
            json = ow.writeValueAsString(jsonInString);

        } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return json;
    }

}
```

Test

```
package hello;

import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.content;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerationException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockServletContext;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MvcResult;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = MockServletContext.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class HelloControllerTest {
    private class User {

        private String name;

        public int getAge() {
            return age;
        }

        void setAge(int age) {
            this.age = age;
        }

        private int age;

        public List<String> getMessages() {
            return messages;
        }

        void setMessages(List<String> messages) {
            this.messages = messages;
        }

        private List<String> messages;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        //getters and setters
    }

    private User createDummyUser() {

        User user = new User();

        user.setName("Mallory");
        user.setAge(33);

        List<String> msg = new ArrayList<>();
        msg.add("hello jackson 1");
        msg.add("hello jackson 2");
        msg.add("hello jackson 3");

        user.setMessages(msg);

        return user;

    }

    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        mvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new HelloController()).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void getHello() throws Exception {

        MvcResult r = mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders
                .get("/")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).andReturn();


        String jsonInString = "";
        String json = "";
        User user = createDummyUser();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            //Convert object to JSON string and save into file directly
            mapper.writeValue(new File("user.json"), user);

            //Convert object to JSON string
            jsonInString = mapper.writeValueAsString(user);
            System.out.println(jsonInString);

            //Convert object to JSON string and pretty print
            jsonInString = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(user);
            ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
            json = ow.writeValueAsString(jsonInString);

            mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/catalogs2").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                    .andExpect(status().isOk())


                    .andExpect(content().string(equalTo(json)));

        } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Test

[image]

Comment: So I can't return an object and have it serialized to JSON in a transparent manner?  The serialization seems to work fine when the service is deployed, but it fails during the tests..

Comment: @FlexFiend I added a more advanced example where you create json from a Java object and serialize it + the test. I hope it can be of use for you.